# Sort datatable column by text instead of it's value

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using a datatable in which I have bind a column like:

```
return `<div>
           <a type="submit"  name="${row.id}" target="${targetPage}" href="${link here}" class="mr-2" data-key="${row.id}" >${row.name}</a>
        </div >`;
```

Here when I am trying to sort this column then it will be sorted by ID (row.id), and I want it to sort column values by text (row.name).

Comment: could you please show the whole code for datatables?

Comment: A hack could be to add an attribute to the `<div>`: for example `return \`<div data-name="${row.name}"><a ...`. This means that the sort (which operates on the entire contents of the column) will be sorted by the first differentiating text it finds in the HTML string - which will now be the value of `${row.name}`. If that does not help, then you do need to show us a [mre].

Comment: A more typical solution would be to use a [column renderer](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) to distinguish displayable data from sortable data.